# Attaching a screen shot in comments

Tags: discussion

I had posted a question regarding disk management - someone while helping me, wanted me to post screen shot of Gparted - screen shot is gathered by me, but while replying his comments, I am not able to attach that file - I need answer how to do the same?

Comment: Obviously you can't post the screenshot, but if you upload the screenshot to any file sharing website and provide a link to it, then someone else will add the screenshot of GParted for you.

Comment: http://imgur.com is the most popular site around here. Just upload your screenshot there and send the link to the people helping you.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, if someone asks you for a clarification of your question/answer, you shouldn't answer them in a comment. You should instead edit your original post. That's precisely why there is no way to include screenshots or other media in comments. Comments are second class citizens here. They are ephemeral and limited in scope. Everything should be done in answers and questions.

So, next time a situation like this arises, don't try to answer with a comment. Edit your post and then leave a comment to whoever asked for clarifications informing them that you have made an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use [imgur.com](https://imgur.com) [image: why can't I add this smiley in?]